# Does FullCalendar support an annual view?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Basically I want to do something like: https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/

I may be being totally blind, but I cannot find any mention of this in the docs  and some searches have not turned up anything helpful. Is it possible to render Full Calendar in a similar way to the above link?

If not, has anyone found an extension that can do this, or do I need to look in more detail at Custom Views (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-views)?

Cheers in advance for any help.

Comment: why not show 12 full calendars in a fixed height and width and each showing a different month?

Comment: There's no built-in view for it no, although I'd be willing to be someone has already made a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) for it. If you google around, you might even find some helpful person has already created a custom view which does the job. Creating a custom view is no small task though - plus you have to maintain it when new versions are released (and v4 is currently in testing, and is a complete almost-ground-up rewrite, so chance are if you designed a custom view for v3 you'd have to re-do it entirely for v4)